# How to insert values into a nested python dictionary

Tags: python, postgresql, dictionary

I am trying to insert values into a nested python dictionary. The response I am getting is from a postgresql database where the table has four columns:

```
coe,  coe_type, count, coe_status
Author 1, Open,       10,    Published
Author 2, Closed,     20,    Not-Published

etc....
```

Currently my response looks like this

```json
  "data": {
    "Author 1": {
      "Open": {},
      "Closed": {},
      "All": {
        "Published": 1,
        "Non-Published": 1
      }
    },
```

The problem I am having is that I want to insert all the counts for each specific type. For instance, Open should have its own Published and Non-Published count. This is the same for Closed as well.

So the response should look like is this

```json
  "data": {
    "beryl": {
      "Open": {
        "Published": 1,
        "Non-Published": 1
     },
      "Closed": {
        "Published": 1,
        "Non-Published": 1
      },
      "All": {
        "Published": 1,
        "Non-Published": 1
      }
    },
```

This is how the current code is written:

```py
category_headers = ["Open", "Published"]
book_main_headers = ["Owner", "Published", "Non-Published"]
book_type_headers=["Open", "Closed", "All"]

        response_result = {}
        last_author = None
        response = execute_query(sql_query, transaction_id, False)

            current_list = ast.literal_eval(row)
            current_author, book, book_count, book_published_non_published = (current_list[0], current_list[1], current_list[2], current_list[3])

            if last_author is None or last_author != current_author:
                interim_dictionary[str(current_author)] = {} 
                last_author = current_author
            for book_type in book_type_headers:
                interim_dictionary[str(current_author)][str(book_type)] = {} 
            for coe_category in category_headers:
                interim_dictionary[str(current_author)][str(book_type)][str(book_category)] = {} 
                if book_category not in interim_dictionary[str(current_author)]:
                    interim_dictionary[str(current_author)][str(book_type)][book_category] = 0
                if book == 'Open':
                    if book_type_headers == 'Published':
                       interim_dictionary[str(current_author)][str(book_type)][book_category] = book_count
                    else:
                        interim_dictionary[str(current_author)][str(book_type)][book_category] = book_count
                if book == 'Closed':
                    if book_type_headers == 'Published':
                       interim_dictionary[str(current_author)][str(book_type)][book_category] = book_count
                    else:
                        interim_dictionary[str(current_author)][str(book_type)][book_category] = book_count
                else:
                    if book_type_headers == 'Published':
                       interim_dictionary[str(current_author)][str(book_type)][book_category] = book_count
                    else:
                        interim_dictionary[str(current_author)][str(book_type)][book_category] = book_count
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in your code. First, your second for loop is outside of the first one, which means the value of `book_type` is always `All` in the rest of your code.

Also the if on line 19 doesn't seem to check the proper condition: shouldn't it be

```
book_category not in interim_dictionary[str(current_author)][str(book_type)]
```

instead of

```
book_category not in interim_dictionary[str(current_author)]
```

You are also comparing lists with a strings:

```
if book_type_headers == 'Published':
```

And finally, all lines from the line 25 do exactly the same thing so the ifs are useless.

Here is how I would write this code:

```
category_headers = ["Open", "Published"]
book_main_headers = ["Owner", "Published", "Non-Published"]
book_type_headers=["Open", "Closed", "All"]

response_result = {}
last_author = None
response = execute_query(sql_query, transaction_id, False)

current_list = ast.literal_eval(row)
current_author, book_type, book_count, book_published_non_published = (current_list[0], current_list[1], current_list[2], current_list[3])

if last_author is None or last_author != current_author:
    # Create empty dictionary for the author
    interim_dictionary[str(current_author)] = { book_type: { category: 0 for category in category_headers } for book_type in book_type_headers }
    last_author = current_author

    # Add books to 'All'
    interim_dictionary[str(current_author)]['All'][book_published_non_published] += book_count

    # Add books to the subdictionary with proper type
    interim_dictionary[str(current_author)][book_type][book_published_non_published] += book_count
```

Comment: Would doing this line `interim_dictionary[str(current_author)]['All'][book_published_non_published] += book_count` not pull a KeyError as it 'All' at that time would not exsist?

Comment: It does exist because of the line 14, that creates an empty subdictionnary:
`interim_dictionary[str(current_author)] = { book_type: { category: 0 for category in category_headers } for book_type in book_type_headers }`